# What's the syntax for .bat?

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file

```
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" @setlocal
...
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" @endlocal
```

Does the above basically mean this:

```
if(OS == 'Windows_NT'):
...
endif
```

?

What's `setlocal` for ?

How do bat identify the `endif`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
setlocal /?
```

on command prompt

As for `if` statements: `help if` should show you everything you need to know. Batch files have only single line `if` statements of the forms

> `if`    [*condition*]    [*statement*]
> `if`    [*condition*]    [*statement*]    `else`    [*statement*]

However, [*statement*] can be a block, delimited by parentheses:

> `if`    [*condition*]    `(`
>     [*statement*]
>     [*statement*]
>     ...
> `)`
>
> `if`    [*condition*]    `(`
>     [*statement*]
>     ...
> `)`    `else`    `(`
>     [*statement*]
>     ...
> `)`

There is no explicit `end if` keyword. The end of the `if` statement is marked by the end of the line or by the end of the parenthesized block.

Also keep in mind that you need to be careful with setting and subsequently using environment variables in a single block. Read up in `help set` on delayed expansion for the pitfalls there.

Comment: Then how does bat indentify the end of `if`?

Comment: @user: as far as I remember .bat files only support single-line if. So the end of the line is the end of the if-statement (maybe it was even single-statement).

Comment: I took the liberty of expanding this on the `end if` issue, trivial as it may be :-)

Comment: Thanks for completing my answer, I've made it as wiki, thanks  Johannes Rössel

Comment: I just tried,`else` seems not supported when the block takes up several lines:if 1 == 1 ( echo 1 echo good ) else ( echo 2 echo bad ),but works when it's single line

Answer (score 2):

http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation based on a practical example: Apache Tomcat**

I chose this example because it has everything that you want to know. I also added some simple examples.

1. ### `"%OS%" == "Windows_NT"`

   It was used in **old versions** of Tomcat (catalina.bat) as:

   ```
   if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal
   ```

   but starting from **Tomcat 8** (at this moment only Tomcat 8 and Tomcat 9 - milestone version are available) it was replaced by:

   ```
   setlocal
   ```

   because `%OS%` is always `Windows_NT` on the new Windows operating system.
   So, on the modern [Microsoft Windows versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions), that `if` is useless. Just use `setlocal`.

   **References**:

   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#OS (Windows) :

     > The **%OS%** variable contains a **symbolic name of the operating system family** to distinguish between differing feature sets in batchjobs. Under **Windows NT**, **Windows 2000**, **Windows XP** and **Windows 7**, it always **holds the string "Windows_NT"**. It resembles an identically named environment variable %OS% found in all DOS-related operating systems of Digital Research-origin like Concurrent DOS, Multiuser DOS, REAL/32, DOS Plus, DR DOS, Novell DOS and OpenDOS.
   - I didn't find any reference for **Windows 8** and **Windows 10**, but I tested it on both of them and it has the same behavior (it contains  "Windows_NT").
   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#.25OS.25 (DOS) :

     > This variable contains the name of the operating system in order to distinguish between different DOS-related operating systems of Digital Research-origin in batch jobs and applications.[5] Known values include "DOSPLUS" (DOS Plus 1.2 in DOS emulation), "CPCDOS 4.1" (DOS Plus 1.2 in CP/M emulation), "DRDOS" (DR DOS 3.31-6.0, DR DOS Panther, DR DOS StarTrek, DR-DOS 7.02[5]-7.05), "EZDOS" (EZ-DOS 3.41), "PALMDOS" and "NetWare PalmDOS" (PalmDOS 1.0), "NWDOS" (Novell DOS 7), "NWDOS7" (Novell DOS 7 Beta), "OPENDOS" (Caldera OpenDOS 7.01, Caldera DR-OpenDOS 7.02), "CDOS" (Concurrent DOS), "CPCDOS" (Concurrent PC DOS), "CDOS386" (Concurrent DOS 386), "DRMDOS" (DR Multiuser DOS), "MDOS" (CCI Multiuser DOS), "REAL32" (REAL/32).[2][6] MS-DOS INTERSVR looks for a value of "DRDOS" as well.[6] See also the identically named environment variable %OS% later introduced in the Microsoft Windows NT family.
2. ### `if`

   In the old **Tomcat** versions (before 8), if the condition `"%OS%" == "Windows_NT"` in `if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal` was false, only `setlocal` would have been skipped. The other commands would have been run normally.

   In **your case**, if the condition is true (and it probably is - see the explanation above), then only **one command will be run** (that virtual `endif` comes exactly at the end of the row - just after `@setlocal`).

   The following **simple example** should be clear:

   ```
   @echo off
   rem testif.bat
   if "1" == "2" echo a
   echo b

   if "1" == "1" echo c
   echo d
   ```

   Running testif.bat from a console prints:

   ```
   b
   c
   d
   ```

   Even if the first condition was false, only `echo a` was influenced by this value because it was skipped. So, the virtual `endif` comes after `echo a` (before `echo b`).
3. ### `setlocal`

   In **Tomcat** (\bin\startup.bat), you can set the `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` variables like this:

   ```
   set CATALINA_HOME=%~dp0
   set CATALINA_BASE=%CATALINA_HOME%
   ```

   **after** the `setlocal` line. If you add those lines before `setlocal`, those two variables will be available after the end of the batch script. They don't have "side-effects" if you run the script using double click (the normal way), but it matters if you want to run it from a command prompt.

   A simplified version:

   ```
   @echo off
   rem 1.bat
   set A=1
   setlocal
   set B=2
   endlocal
   set C=3
   ```

   Run the script above (`1.bat`) from a command prompt and after that run, run the following commands:

   ```
   rem - prints 1
   echo %A%
   rem - prints %B%
   echo %B%
   rem - prints 3
   echo %C%
   ```

   So, because you don't want to have values for `A` and `C`, you should set the environment variable between `setlocal` and `endlocal`. Of course, if you run the same `echo` commands from a new prompt, none of them will be set (the output will be `%A%`, `%B%`, `%C%`).

   If there is no explicit `endlocal`, imagine that it's at the end of the batch file:

   **Reference:**

   - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491001.aspx

     > Use **setlocal** to change environment variables when you run a batch file. Environment changes made after you run setlocal are local to the batch file. Cmd.exe restores previous settings when it either encounters an **endlocal** command **or reaches the end of the batch file**.